# I have called functions, but that still outputs nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, global-variables

I am at a loss why for a fraction of a second a new window is opened when I run this python script from command prompt (by using python3.8 testGlob.py). But I mean there is nothing wrong with it. No errors. It just does nothing, prints nothing in the main terminal/ cmd window! I added the print('Starting program') to test this, and yeah. I get nothing in the cmd window.

```
#import config
from config import *


def testFunc():
    print('Test Func:')
    print('Time Flag:', config.HBTimeFlag)

    print('Sent Flag', config.HBSentFlag)

    config.HBTimeFlag = True

def test2Func():
    print('Test2 Func:')
    print('Time Flag:', config.HBTimeFlag)

    print('Sent Flag', config.HBSentFlag)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting program')
    testFunc()
    test2Func()
```

The config. py file is literally only this:

```
HBSentFlag = False

HBTimeFlag = False
```

In the end, I am trying to import the variables from the config file, assign values to them and use them across multiple functions in the main program.

I would love to get an answer both for the first and then the second part of the question (the final functionality desired).

Thank you!

EDIT 1:
Adding a link with a video showing what is happening. (This is after adding a **init**.py file and using import config).
Here's the [video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/xV3bWaWS3kGauXP59).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your program did not detect if it was a main module. Change import back to `import config`. Try `python testGlob.py`. It works on mine.  In your video, you only typed the name of the file without python or python3.

```
Starting program
Test Func:
Time Flag: False
Sent Flag False
Test2 Func:
Time Flag: True
Sent Flag False
```

Your program also launched another windows and closed immediately. It may run in a different window. Try to read an input after calling the function.

Comment: Literally the only issue was that instead of typing python3.8 filename.py as I usually do I was typing just the name of the program. Thank you. I thought I as going crazy!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an empty file called `__init__.py` beside `testGlob.py`/`config.py` and change your import to `import config`. When I do these 2 things, it works for me running `python testGlob.py`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But that did not work. Please check the edit I have made. I have added a video showing what is happening.

Comment: Did you try running the command like I said in my answer? `python testGlob.py`